# Extreme hardening of my Macbook pro from physical hacking

Tags: macos, security, encryption, privacy, hacking

Is the a way to double encrypt my macbook pro?

I have followed a guide to harden my macbook pro but I wanted to know if I can harden it more. I have for example used file vault to encrypt my disk and i have put a firmware password on it also. Is there more I can do? I want to make it as difficult as possible to extract information from my hard drive if stolen or lost as there are sensitive documents and details on it....

Comment: The best advice I can give for security is to write down your threat model[s). Your model of unattended physical access is solid, but we have no idea what steps you followed or why FileVault isn’t good enough in your case.

Comment: There is a recent post [here at AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406757/make-filevault-password-different-from-user-login-password/406758#406758) which asks about using an alternate password than the user login password for FileVault. Remember to encrypt your Time Machine backup disk(s) as well if you use Time Machine.

Comment: Note that **any** port (usb, video, SD card, headphone, etc.) on your Mac is a potential vector for hackers. It just depends on who you are protecting against. The NSA? you might as well just hand them the laptop and your password. Without closing up all of the ports with superglue and plugs there is no way to make any computer completely hack proof. It just depends on who is doing it and how much time and energy and $$ they have to dedicate to getting in.